# Performing deconvolution to solve for x given y and h where y = h*x (all column vectors)

Tags: matlab, matrix, convolution, deconvolution

The Matlab has its built-in function deconv() which performs deconvolution perfectly. However, I was trying to make another simple implementation using the property of Toeplitz matrix in calculating convolution, but it seems to be not universal. Can anyone help me modify it, please?

```
function x = mdeconv(h, y)
%Deconvolution
%
hT = toeplitz([h(1) zeros(1,length(y)-length(h))], [h zeros(1,length(y)-length(h)) ]);
%x = linsolve(hT, y);
x = y/hT;
end
```

P.S. It can also be done using Fourier transform in signal processing, but my goal was to perform deconvolution with matrix operations.

Comment: "Write code for me" is not a question about programming. It looks like you want to hire a programmer, I'm sure there's websites for that, but Stack Overflow is not.

Comment: @Cris Luengo I am just asking if anyone can help me modify my code to make it more universal.  I have modified my illustration to avoid misunderstanding.